# if I have a reserved instance (windows), can I use it for an equivalent linux version?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Both linux and windows reserved instances have the same deposit, so can I switch between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike normal on-demand EC2 instances (where the image decides the OS), the RESERVED instances cannot be changed after purchasing.  To quote [the official documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/):

> Platform (e.g. Linux/UNIX, SUSE Linux,
>   Windows Server, or Amazon VPC with
>   either Operating System), Instance
>   Type, Availability Zone, and term
>   length must be chosen at purchase, and
>   cannot be changed later.

Comment: that really sucks!